# For Loop to Recursion Statement - Syntax

Tags: recursion

I was asked to create an assignment with the output: That would look like and execute like the following as long as the number is positive.

```
Please enter a number: 4
****
***
**
*
**
***
****
```

This works correctly with the for loop in which was created: However, I was told no for loop or any loop of any matter could be used. I was asked to change this to a recursive method and utilize the call in (2) if else statements. However, I have read all available published paper to change a for loop into recursive but I have been unsuccessful I would greatly appreciate some help to understanding with some in depth clarification.

```
    static void printPattern(int pattern) {
        for (int i=0; i<pattern; ++i) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void printStars(int lines) {
        if (lines<=1) {
            printPattern(1);
        } else {
            printPattern(lines);
            printStars(lines-1);
            printPattern(lines);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted looks like it should work, right? What are you stuck on?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  Specifically, post your *entire* program *and* the output you got (you've already included the expected output).  I should be able to paste your code into my environment, compile and execute it as is, and receive the output that's giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
static void printPattern(int pattern) {

    if(pattern>0){
        System.out.print("*");
        printPattern(--pattern);
    }else{
        System.out.println();
    }   
}
```